# Diagonalising a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, matrix-multiplication

I'm doing some matrix algebra using the very lovely `pandas` library in Python. I'm really enjoying using the Series and Dataframe objects because of the ability to name rows and columns.

But is there a neat way to diagonalise a Series while maintaining row/column names?

Consider this minimum working example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series(randn(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
>>> s
a    0.137477
b   -0.606762
c    0.085030
d   -0.571760
e   -0.475104
dtype: float64
```

Now, I can do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.diag(s)
array([[ 0.13747693,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.60676226,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.08502993,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.57176048,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.47510435]])
```

But I'd love to find a way of producing a Dataframe that looks like:

```
          a         b        c        d         e
0  0.137477  0.000000  0.00000  0.00000  0.000000
1  0.000000 -0.606762  0.00000  0.00000  0.000000
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.08503  0.00000  0.000000
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000 -0.57176  0.000000
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000  0.00000 -0.475104
```

or perhaps even (which would be even better!):

```
          a         b        c        d         e
a  0.137477  0.000000  0.00000  0.00000  0.000000
b  0.000000 -0.606762  0.00000  0.00000  0.000000
c  0.000000  0.000000  0.08503  0.00000  0.000000
d  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000 -0.57176  0.000000
e  0.000000  0.000000  0.00000  0.00000 -0.475104
```

This would be great because then I could do matrix operations like:

```
>>> S.dot(s)
a    0.018900
c    0.368160
b    0.007230
e    0.326910
d    0.225724
dtype: float64
```

and retain the names.

Many thanks in advance, as always.
Rob

Comment: Note: I realise that the final example `S.dot(s)` is pretty dumb and could be achieved with `s * s` but it's just to serve as an example!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this..

```
In [107]: pd.DataFrame(np.diag(s),index=s.index,columns=s.index)
Out[107]: 
          a         b         c         d         e
a  0.630529  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
b  0.000000  0.360884  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
c  0.000000  0.000000  0.345719  0.000000  0.000000
d  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.796625  0.000000
e  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 -0.176848
```

Comment: updated (though in your original post it looked like you wanted a number range in index, but up 2 you)

Comment: Ha ha! I think I beat you to it by a couple of seconds. Thanks so much Jeff. Great solution.