# Diagonalizing a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_foo = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
```

I believe I used to be able to diagonalize this DataFrame as follows (see e.g. this thread [Diagonalising a Pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408896/diagonalising-a-pandas-series))

```
df_foo_diag = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(df_foo), index=df_foo.index, columns = df_foo.index)
```

However, when I do this now, it seems that `np.diag(df_foo)` returns a 1 by 1 array containing the first value of the DataFrame. In other words, it seems like numpy extracts the diagonal, instead of constructing a diagonal array.

How can I construct a diagonal DataFrame out of a 1-dimensional DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert one column Dataframe to `Series` by [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) and then your solution working well:

```
df_foo_diag = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(df_foo.squeeze()), 
                           index=df_foo.index, 
                           columns = df_foo.index)
print (df_foo_diag)
   0  1  2
0  1  0  0
1  0  2  0
2  0  0  3
```

---

```
df_foo = pd.DataFrame([10,20,30])

df_foo_diag = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(df_foo.squeeze()), 
                           index=df_foo.index, 
                           columns = df_foo.index)
print (df_foo_diag)
    0   1   2
0  10   0   0
1   0  20   0
2   0   0  30
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense to use a 2D input.

Just use the relevant column of your DataFrame, and you'll have the original case:

```
df_foo_diag = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(df_foo[0]),
                           index=df_foo.index, columns=df_foo.index)
```

output:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  0  0
1  0  2  0
2  0  0  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply flatten your 1D Dataframe

```
df_foo_diag = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(df_foo.to_numpy().flatten()), 
index=df_foo.index, columns = df_foo.index)


print(df_foo_diag)

    0   1   2
0   1   0   0
1   0   2   0
2   0   0   3
```